Varnish - How to set timeout_idle in VCL config file?
I have a Varnish running with default timeout_idle value of 5 seconds.
I want to modify it and would like to know where I must add in the VCL config file.
I guess it should be in "vcl_init":
sess.timeout_idle = 360;

I must do it through config file and not command line option.
Here is the extract of my VCL config file, I've remove the not relevant code, which is working file:
sub vcl_init {

    # Called when VCL is loaded, before any requests pass through it.
    # Typically used to initialize VMODs.

    # working settings (removed)

    sess.timeout_idle = 360;
}


